# Post a feed with a link without 'shared as link'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I searched for an hour before posting this question so please forgive me in advance if this is a basic, dense question.  I feel like there must be something simple I'm not wrapping my head around.

I see many apps, e.g. "WeForPresident" which when joined, post a simple feed.  It contains no special formatting, just an image, a link to an external site and some text.

I cannot find a way to do this with the graph api.  When I post using the link param, I get 'shared a link' formatting, which is undesired.  And yet, using the message param does not allow linking.

So, how are apps such as WeForPresident achieving this effect?

Thanks again.

---

Bounty Info

Using /TEST_USER_ID/feed with message, link, description, picture, name

Posts as a link

[image: Link as "shared via"]

With actions param added

[image: Link without "shared via"]

And the application in question the user talks about

[image: without "shared"]

Notice no Share mentioned anywhere in the post

Comment: I added the facebook tag to your question. If this is not correct, please remove it and add another tag to make your question more understandable.

Comment: Thank you.  I thought I was on the facebook subdomain; will watch out for that in the future.

Comment: I've added a bounty (forgot to add a message) the answer I am looking for should explain how one gets a `shared_story` type vs. `app_created_story` type for the `status_type`

Comment: Is this the type of thing you are looking for? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: @sinisterfrog yeah though that seems to be a dialog whereas with WeForPresident I didn't hit a dialog

Comment: The only correct answer here is the one by @phwd which is sadly on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 6):

Are you talking about something like this?

[image]

That's possible through Open Graph Objects and Actions.  Here's a brief (and hopefully not terribly confusing) breakdown:

Object: In the image above, the object is "pet who needs a home".  An object is text to describe the page you happen to be sharing, and is referenced in the header tags of the page you're sharing (more on that soon.)

Action: In the above image, refers to "shared" in the "... **shared** a pet who needs a home...".  Actions are whatever it is that you're actually doing with open graph.  I've seen sites "**sign** a petition on so-and-so" or "**play** such-and-such a word on this-and-that app".  The bolded words are the action.

Both actions and object types can be defined on http://developers.facebook.com.  If / when you have an app, and you opt to use Open Graph, it encourages you to create at least one action and one object type.  There are a number of predefined ones ("reading a book", "cooking a recipe", "watching a video", etc...).  Actions and objects help you personalize the messages you post to people's walls.

It's worth noting that if you define a custom Action, Facebook needs to approve it before they're willing to let just anyone use it.  Normally it's not terribly difficult...you just have to click on a "Submit" button next to the Action and it will tell you if / when it gets approved.

---

So now we've gotten the basics out of the way, let's talk about how to implement something like this on your pages.  As I'm sure you're well aware, Open Graph makes use of FB.api() instead of FB.ui().  I'm going to use a Javascript example here.

```
  FB.api(
    '/me/app_namespace:share',
    'post',
    {
       pet_who_needs_a_home: document.location.href,
       image: pet_image // optional
    },
    function(response) {
      // You can do something with the response here.
      // If successful, Facebook returns the post id of the post it just made
      // If it fails, check response.error
    }
  );
```

There's also two very important tags that you need in your <head> tag.  And here they are:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR_APP_ID" />
<meta property="og:type" content="APP_NAMESPACE:pet_who_needs_a_home" />
```

Now let me talk you through what everything is.  FB.api() is rather obvious so I'll skip onto...

```
'/me/app_namespace:share',
```

/me is posting to your wall.  app_namespace is the namespace found in your app details section on developers.facebook.com.  You may need to define a namespace (settings->basic->second text box).  the ":" breaks the namespace and action.  Share is the action (defined, again, on developers.facebook.com).

```
'post',
```

Tells Facebook that we want to use a POST request (as opposed to a GET request).

```
{
   pet_who_needs_a_home: document.location.href,
   image: pet_image // optional
},
```

This is (obviously) a javascript array of two important values.  "pet_who_needs_a_home" is the  (actually my...you should replace that with whatever yours is) object type (still on developers.facebook.com) which, as you recall, helps us define the language used, like in the image above.  Image is an optional field in which you can define the image that will be shared through open graph.  There are a slew of other optional fields that you can check at...you know.

```
function(response) {
```

...and all that is kind of obvious so I'll spare the pointless details there.  As I mentioned in the comments, it returns either the post id of the post if successful, or an error (found in response.error) that may or may not be descriptive.

The meta tags, I hope, speak for themselves.  YOUR_APP_ID is...you guessed it...your app ID.  All numeric.  app_namespace is your namespace, again.  pet_who_needs_a_home is (my) object and should be replaced with whatever object you happen to be using.

---

Sorry for the long post.  Hopefully that sort of cleared that up a little bit.

Comment: Nice work, updated with some images above. Maybe that will give better insight

Answer (score 3):

this will post the exact same post as of weForPresident via your appName. please change your messages accordingly. and access token should have publish_actions extended permission

```
$attachment =  array(
                          'access_token' => $access_token,
                          'message' => "I Just Join WeForPresident",
                          'name' => "WeForPresident",
                          'description' => "philippe harewood just started gamng the election on weForPresident and could possibly win some cool stuff",
                          'link' => "any link to external site",
                          'picture' => "image link to display in left box"
                      );

   $facebook->api("me/feed","POST",$attachment);
```

hope it helps.

update: javascript dialog for above solution will be something like below, which will prompt user to post and so will not need publish_actions extended permission:

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
            xmlns:fb='https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml'>
            <head>
              <title>My Feed Dialog Page</title>
            </head>
            <body>
              <div id='fb-root'></div>
              <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
              <p id='msg'></p>
              <script>
                FB.init({appId: '#############', status: true, cookie: true});


                  // calling the API ...
                  var obj = {
                    method: 'feed',
                    link: 'any external url',
                    picture: 'picture url to show up in left',
                    name: 'name of the post: comes as heading in blue color within box',
                    description: 'post description, that comes within box'

                    };

                  function callback(response) {

                  }

                  FB.ui(obj, callback);

              </script>
            </body>
          </html>";
```

**complete code for such post** : first download the php-sdk from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

```
<?php
include_once "facebook-sdk/facebook.php"; 
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId' => APP_ID,
          'secret' => APP_SECRET,
        ));
if(isset($_GET['code']))
            {

                 $access_token = $facebook->getAccessTokenFromCode($_GET['code'],$_SESSION['redirect_uri']);

                $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
         $attachment =  array(
                          'access_token' => $access_token,
                          'message' => "$message",
                          'name' => "$name",
                          'description' => "$description",
                          'link' => "any external link",
                          'picture' => "picture url"
                      );

        $facebook->api("me/feed","POST",$attachment);
       }
         else
         {

            $scope = "publish_stream";
            $params = array('scope' => $scope);
            $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");

         }
?>
```

Comment: I still end up getting this http://i.stack.imgur.com/68fa7.png (This was done via the Graph API Explorer as a POST request, if that matters)

Comment: yes, that may cause the problem. I use the exact same code (first one if publish_actions permission I get and second one if i dont) and we both case, it goes as post. see ['a post from my app'](http://www.facebook.com/alex.alliee/posts/3201661298917) . so please try with the application once, i am sure it will work coz it does for me.

Comment: Here it is within a self contained example, same result https://gist.github.com/3905093

Comment: can you try using `facebook-php-sdk` for authentication and posting on wall ?

Comment: check the edit, thats how you can post using php-sdk. it should work for you as well

Comment: Still returns the post with the share included, also your latest example is `publish_stream` not `publish_actions`

Answer (score 2):

This ended up being a bug which is not fixed and has a current state of "triaged"

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/138798476259001

The only solution so far seems to be adding the action paramaters